# how to fix value to be entered in search box in selenium with java which is getting entered recent copy pasted value on the system

Tags: java, selenium

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
I am facing scenario as below:
I am executing a method where I need to enter a value from excel sheet in the search box but at the run time value getting entered is recent copy pasted value in the system how to tackle this issue?
Though this same code is working absolutely fine in my other test conditions but is failing in only one test condition.

```
String newParentContent = excel.getCellData(sheetName, parContent, row);
logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "The respective parent content" + newParentContent ); 
Thread.sleep(3000); 
UtilMethods.setText(logger, parentContentInput, newParentContent);
```

Comment: Please add your code and output/exception/screenshot.

Comment: this is my code
 
 String newParentContent = excel.getCellData(sheetName, parContent, row);
         
         logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "The respective parent content" + newParentContent );
         Thread.sleep(3000);
         UtilMethods.setText(logger, parentContentInput, newParentContent);

Comment: Did you check what this returns `newParentContent `?

Comment: yes I did check its returning correct value from excel sheet. Please see the link for screen shot which i have added in main post

Comment: Can you post the `UtilMethods.setText()` method?

Comment: public static void setText(ExtentTest logger, WebElement we, String data) {
  try {
   we.clear();
   we.sendKeys(data);
   logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Keys sent as: " + data);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   System.out.println(e.getCause());
   logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Failed to send keys due to <b style='color:red'>" + e.getClass() + "<br>"
     + e.getMessage() + "</b>");
  }
 }